# Python - Suggestions on using model in production 1 test at a time

Tags: python, neural-network, categorical-data, feature-selection

I have created an Artificial Neural Network with 4 categorical features and a binary outcome either 1 for suspicious or 0 for non-suspicious:

```
  ParentPath                                  ParentExe
0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe
1   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  WrlsAutoSW.exs
2   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  WrlsAutoSW.exs
3   C:\Windows\System32                         svchost.exe
4   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  WrlsAutoSW.exs

ChildPath                                   ChildExe    Suspicious
C:\Windows\System32                         conhost.exe  0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe   0 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe   0
C:\Program Files\Common Files               OfficeC2RClient.exe  0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe  1
C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe  0
```

I have used sklearn for label encoding and one hot encoding on the data:

```
#Import the dataset
X = DBF2.iloc[:, 0:4].values
#X = DBF2[['ParentProcess', 'ChildProcess']]
y = DBF2.iloc[:, 4].values#.ravel()

#Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
#Label Encode Parent Path
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
#Label Encode Parent Exe
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
#Label Encode Child Path
labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_3.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
#Label Encode Child Exe
labelencoder_X_4 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X_4.fit_transform(X[:, 3])

#Create dummy variables
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0,1,2,3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X)
```

I have split the data into a training and test set and run it on my gpu box with a nvidia 1080.  I have tuned the hyperparameters and am now ready to use the model that is trained in a production environment with one test sample being tested at a time.  Lets say I just want to test one sample:

```
   ParentPath            ParentExe     ChildPath           ChildExe
0  C:\Windows\Malicious  badscipt.exe  C:\Windows\System   cmd.exe
```

The issue that I am running into is the training set has seen the ChildPath "C:\Windows\System" and the ChildExe "cmd.exe"  which are normal, but the training set has not seen the ParentPath "C:\Windows\Malicous" or ParentExe "badscipt.exe" so these have not been label or one hot encoded.  My big question is how do I handle one test feature where part of it has not been trained?

I have seen examples using feature hashing but im not sure how to apply that or if that would even solve this problem.  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create data frame with malicous test
testmalicious = {'ParentProcess': ['ParentProcess': ['C:\Windows\System32\services.exe'], 'ChildProcess': ['C:\Windows\System32\svch0st.exe'], 'Suspicous': [1]}
testmaliciousdf = pd.DataFrame(data=testmalicious)
testmaliciousdf = testmaliciousdf[['ParentProcess', 'ChildProcess', 'Suspicous']]
#Add the malicious to the end of dataframe
DBF1 = DBF2.append(testmaliciousdf)
DBF2 = DBF1.reset_index(drop=True)
#Location where mal_array sample is located - after label and one hot encoded pull out of training set
mal_array = X[368827:368828]
#Remove the last line of the array from training set
X=X[:-1]
#Remove the last line of the array from the y data
y=y[:-1]
#At the end test if suspicious or not
new_prediction = classifier.predict(sc.transform(mal_array))
new_prediction = (new_prediction > 0.5)
new_prediction
```